# Stub regex in rspec

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec

How can a regex be stubed?
e.g.

```
# somewhere deep in the code
reg = Regexp.new("foo bar")
res = reg.match string

# somewhere in rspec
reg = Regexp.new("foo bar")
reg.stub(:match).with(string).and_return "rspec_res" #doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
reg = stub :match => "rspec_res"
Regex.stub(:new) { reg }
```